# ¿Por qué este script no carga valores en las variables?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Aprendiendo clases. ¿Por qué el ejercicio que muestro a continuación, me devuelve la variable **retornos_diarios** vacía?.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

class ImportaYahoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df_apple = pd.DataFrame({})
        self.apple_close = pd.DataFrame({})    
    
    def importar_cotizaciones (self):
        # Importar cotizaciones de Apple
        import yfinance
        name = 'AAPL'
        ticker = yfinance.Ticker(name)
        self.df_apple = ticker.history(interval="1d",start="2017-01-4",end="2021-04-10")
        self.apple_close = sel.df_apple[["Close"]]

class CalculaVariaciones (ImportaYahoo):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        self.retornos_diarios = pd.DataFrame({})
        self.log_retornos_diarios = pd.DataFrame({})
        
    def calc_retornos_diarios(self):
        # Porcentaje de variación diaria
        self.retornos_diarios = self.apple_close.pct_change()
        self.retornos_diarios.fillna(0, inplace=True)
        self.retornos_diarios.dropna(inplace = True)
    
    def calc_log_retornos_diarios(self):
        self.log_retornos_diarios = np.log(self.retornos_diarios + 1)
        
class DibujaHistograma(CalculaVariaciones):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   
        
    def mostrar_histograma (self):
        # Plot the histogram
        print("\n*******************************************************")        
        self.retornos_diarios.hist(bins = 100, color='blue', figsize=(15, 8))
        plt.ylabel('Frecuencia')
        plt.xlabel('Retornos diarios')
        plt.title('Histograma de los retornos diarios')
        plt.show()        
        
histograma =  DibujaHistograma()
histograma.importar_cotizaciones
histograma.calc_retornos_diarios()
histograma.mostrar_histograma()
```

Me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-aba7212a4adb> in <module>
     49 histograma.importar_cotizaciones
     50 histograma.calc_retornos_diarios()
---> 51 histograma.mostrar_histograma()
     52 

<ipython-input-33-aba7212a4adb> in mostrar_histograma(self)
     40         # Plot the histogram
     41         print("\n*******************************************************")
---> 42         self.retornos_diarios.hist(bins = 100, color='blue', figsize=(15, 8))
     43         plt.ylabel('Frecuencia')
     44         plt.xlabel('Retornos diarios')

~/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in hist_frame(data, column, by, grid, xlabelsize, xrot, ylabelsize, yrot, ax, sharex, sharey, figsize, layout, bins, backend, legend, **kwargs)
    209     """
    210     plot_backend = _get_plot_backend(backend)
--> 211     return plot_backend.hist_frame(
    212         data,
    213         column=column,

~/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/hist.py in hist_frame(data, column, by, grid, xlabelsize, xrot, ylabelsize, yrot, ax, sharex, sharey, figsize, layout, bins, legend, **kwds)
    425 
    426     if naxes == 0:
--> 427         raise ValueError(
    428             "hist method requires numerical or datetime columns, nothing to plot."
    429         )

ValueError: hist method requires numerical or datetime columns, nothing to plot.
```

Comment: Las fechas no lo esta tomando como `datetime`

Comment: He añadido "import datetime as dt" ,  "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" y una invocación al método "histograma.importar_cotizaciones()". Ahora ya opera correctamente.

Comment: Que bueno que hayas resuelto tu problema :) Felicidades!